# Slycot DLL Failure: Windows 10 Python 3.10 & 3.11

Tags: python

This has been solved via GitHub issue [#219](https://github.com/python-control/Slycot/issues/219), but I decided to post here for those using the Python Control package, since most people look here first.

Problem:  `import slycot` fails with a

```
    from . import _wrapper
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _wrapper: The specified module could not be found.
```

on Anaconda versions supporting Python 3.10 and 3.11.  See the comments made by bnavigator at the link above regarding the fix he pushed to the conda slycot package repository.

Given the efforts of both bnavigator and pichim, there are two ways to address this issue.

Create a new environment (Validated for 3.10, 3.11, and 3.12):

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda update --all
conda create -n control_311 pytest numpy scipy sympy control matplotlib ipykernel slycot mplcursors python=3.11
```

Fixing a base install, where `control` and `slycot` have already been installed, but slycot fails:

```
conda update --all
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
conda install conda-forge slycot
```

The latter method preserves your environment, which is what many will want to do.  It is likely that a variant of this method will work for environments, so maybe someone can post in a comment or edit this post appropriately if it does.

Comment: Please split this into a question according to [ask] and an answer according to [answer]. Otherwise the only thing that you cause are misled "Thank you" posts, like the one that is (probably soon deleted) below.